# How to programmatically drive ISR on M0+

Tags: c, unit-testing, arm, embedded, isr

I'm writing some `Unity` unit tests for an embedded project running on an Arm M0+. Some of my APIs depend on wether they're called from the ISR context or not. So I want to programmatically drive an interrupt. In pseudo code, I want my test to look something like:

```
// set (global) flag indicating what ISR should do
// trigger the ISR
// control transfers to ISR which branches off of (global) flag and computes result, store in some global
// control now returns to here, where I can assert the nature of the global result
```

The part that I need some direction in is how to trigger the ISR. I saw some references in the M3 docs about a Software Interrupt Trigger, but I'm not finding anything like that for M0+.

A "workaround" solution might be to grab an unused timer, use it's ISR, then set it's compare to 0, and start it so it drives the interrupt. Or maybe a similar scheme with an unused pin which I configure? Is there a more direct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just wire some output to an input and trigger the interrupt by that input... But surely you have an `svc` instruction triggering an exception.

Comment: ISPR is writable. Just set the interrupt pending.

Comment: What interrupt would I use then? I'm using a small embedded OS, which seems to be doing stuff with SVC and PendSV. Is it legal to use one of the "reserved" slots in the vector table? They're mapped to DummyHandler at the moment, can I just map one of those to function, and then write the associated IRQn to ISPR?

Comment: You might try to use the interrupt for an unused peripheral. Define your own handler and set the interrupt to pending. Nature should then take its course.

Comment: You should probably open a new question rather than appending your query about the vector table onto this one.

Comment: I was hoping someone would actually put up a legit answer to either the original or derived question. Seems more and more people just answer in comment, but then you can't approve an answer :(

Comment: @DKrueger : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721785/is-it-possible-to-set-isr-handler-at-runtime-on-m0

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hints from @user58697 and @andymango, I came up with the following scheme.

-1 Determined that for my board (SAMD21), there was no peripheral at IRQ 21.

-2 Copying the other alias dummy handlers in my resetVectors.c file, I added:

```
void PV21Handler             ( void ) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Dummy_Handler")));
```

-3 Modified the DeviceVectors structure to set .pvReserved21 to that:

```
__attribute__ ((section(".vectors")))
const DeviceVectors exception_table = {
    ...
    ...
    .pvReserved21           = (void*) PV21Handler,
    ...
    ...
};
```

-4 Implemented a void PV21Handler(void) { } function that actually does something

-5 Used the following to enable the interrupt:

```
NVIC_EnableIRQ(21);
// this comes from the core_cm0plus.h file
```

-6 Finally trigger the interrupt with:

```
while (NVIC_GetPendingIRQ(21)) {  }
NVIC_SetPendingIRQ(21);
while (NVIC_GetPendingIRQ(21)) {  }
```

The poll for clear status was necessary since there seems to be a slight delay between setting the interrupt and it actually happening, so to get a true edge, I had to assert it low first.